# Cannot format chart title in gnuplotrb (ruby)

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplotrb (0.3.4) and want to set the font and color of the title independently from the rest of the plot. So far without success.

The example below is a slightly modified version of the [sample code](https://github.com/dilcom/gnuplotrb/blob/master/examples/use_multi_word_option_keys/plot.rb).
(I added a \n to the title and added the title_font option).

Here are my questions with regards to gnuplotrb:

1. How do I set title's font, color, etc.?
2. Can I use multi-line titles (I added '\n' to the title, but this just truncates the string)?
3. How do I set labels in my plot with gnuplotrb?
4. Is there a way to inspect the generated gnuplot script (not the resulting plot, but the actual gnuplot script that is piped to gnuplot)?

`

```
require 'gnuplotrb'
include GnuplotRB

titles = %w{decade Build Test Deploy Overall}
data = [
  [1,  312, 525,  215, 1052],
  [2,  630, 1050, 441, 2121],
  [3,  315, 701,  370, 1386],
  [4,  312, 514,  220, 1046]
]
x = data.map(&:first)
datasets = (1..4).map do |col|
  y = data.map { |row| row[col] }
  Dataset.new([x, y], using: '2:xtic(1)', title: titles[col], file: true)
end

plot = Plot.new(
  *datasets,
  style_data: 'histograms',
  style_fill: 'pattern border',
  yrange: 0..2200,
  xlabel: 'Number of test',
  ylabel: 'Time, s',
  title: "Time spent\nto run deploy pipeline",
  title_font: 'System,20'
)

plot.to_png("test.png")
```

Comment: You should give this the gnuplot tag so that people knowing gnuplot will see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The title's font is set with `title_font`, but you must include additional quotes around the value:

   ```
   title_font: '",20"'
   ```

   The values of some options (like `title`, `xlabel` etc are automatically wrapped with a pair of double quotes by `gnuplotrb`).

   To set the title color, use e.g.

   ```
   title_tc_rgb: '"red"'
   ```
2. Escape the backslash of the newline to get a line break in the output

   ```
   title: "First line\\nSecond line"
   ```
3. Labels can be set like other options

   ```
   label: "at graph 0.1, graph 0.8 'My Label'"
   ```
4. I haven't found an option to redirect the commands to a file.

So, a working example based on your script is

```
require 'gnuplotrb'
include GnuplotRB

titles = %w{decade Build Test Deploy Overall}
data = [
  [1,  312, 525,  215, 1052],
  [2,  630, 1050, 441, 2121],
  [3,  315, 701,  370, 1386],
  [4,  312, 514,  220, 1046]
]
x = data.map(&:first)
datasets = (1..4).map do |col|
  y = data.map { |row| row[col] }
  Dataset.new([x, y], using: '2:xtic(1)', title: titles[col], file: true)
end

plot = Plot.new(
  *datasets,
  style_data: 'histograms',
  style_fill: 'pattern border',
  yrange: 0..2200,
  xlabel: 'Number of test',
  ylabel: 'Time, s',
  label: 'at graph 0.1, graph 0.8 "MyLabel"',
  title: "Time spent\\nto run deploy pipeline",
  title_font: '",20"',
  title_tc_rgb: '"red"'
)

plot.to_png("test.png")
```

with the output file

[image]